# Trying to load google charts into div with jQuery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

Using a simple google chart, I am trying to use jQuery .load to push/pull that chart into another web page which will have the containing DIV:

```
  <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"],callback:drawChart});

function drawChart() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
['2004',  1000,      400],
['2005',  1170,      460],
['2006',  660,       1120],
['2007',  1030,      540]
]);

var options = {
title: 'Company Performance',
hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="test_div">this div loads fine</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is a sample page that will have the containing DIV:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1query.min.js">  
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_div').load('chart.html #chart_div', function() { drawChart(); });
     });
     </script>
     <div id="my_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

I have tried various loading techniques by removing google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
and replacing it with the $document.ready but nothing seems to work.

I have gone through each one of the similar questions posted here but cannot seem to get this working.

any insight appreciated, Thanks!
edit: I noticed that by adding this line to the "container.html" file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

and changing:

```
    $('#my_div').load('chart.html #chart_div', function() { drawChart(); });
```

to

```
   $('#my_div').load('chart.html', function() { drawChart(); });
```

or even:

```
   $('#my_div').load('chart.html');
```

It will indeed load the whole page into "#mydiv" but what I want is to just load the specific "#chart_div" into "#mydiv"

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem. My google chart not load with jquery version 1.11.1
if you remove jquery-1.11.1 or similar and add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("search", "1");
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>`
```

its working

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me.
exactly how did you use it?

Comment: what are your other js imports?

Comment: put this script before all